# add listener to radio field in sencha

Tags: radio-button, listener, sencha-touch

I am creating radiofields in my web app programatically which are initially checked. I am trying to add a listener to the radio field, which listens to ''uncheck' event. On getting unchecked I want to destroy the radio field.

The radio field is added and created just fin but on unchecking the field I get the following error.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of null`

The code for initialising radio field.

```
var radioField= Ext.create('Ext.field.Radio',{
            id:fieldName,
                checked:true,
        label:fieldName,
         listeners: {
          uncheck: function() {
          console.log('destroy');
          destroy();
        }
      }
});
Ext.getCmp('filterListField').add(radioField);
```

Comment: found the error: was generating error when there was a single radio field.
Using checkbox instead worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe name is a required property for radiobox.  I did this and it seems to work.

```
var radioField = Ext.create('Ext.field.Radop', {
                    id: fieldName,
                    checked: true,
                    name:fieldName,
                    label: fieldName,
                    listeners: {
                        'uncheck': function(radio) {
                            console.log('destroy');
                            radio.destroy();
                        }
                    }
                });
 Ext.getCmp('QC23View').add(radioField);
```